# Adding multiple UIImages to a UIStackView with the same name

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to add images to a stack view based on the value of the variable 'num'. Every odd image should be an image called "girl" and even an image called "boy", both of which reside in my assets folder.  Right now the updateSilhouetteView() function is being called by ViewDidLoad.
Everything works perfectly for num < 3, but it stops adding them after there is already one of each image. 
Does swift have a problem with images of the same name? How can I get around this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var silhouetteStack: UIStackView!
let boy = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boy"))
let girl = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "girl"))
var silhouettes: [UIImageView] = []
var num = 3
func updateSilhouetteView() {
    for n in 0..<num {
        if n % 2 == 0 {
            silhouettes.append(boy)
            silhouettes[n].image = UIImage(named: "boy")
            print("boy")
        } else {
            silhouettes.append(girl)
            silhouettes[n].image = UIImage(named: "girl")
            print("girl")
        }
        silhouettes[n].frame = CGRect(x: 210, y: 500, width: 205, height: 120)
        silhouettes[n].contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        silhouetteStack.addArrangedSubview(silhouettes[n])
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the GitHub link to your code? I think my answer should help you but if it doesn't I can look into your code and try to help you.

Comment: @ParthTamane I don't really have a project yet.  I just threw a few things into an empty project to test these concepts before I start building the actual app.  I'm very new to this...

Comment: Okay! Can you check if my answer helps?

Comment: I would think @ParthTamane answer should work for you. The way you're doing it you're only using the original UIImageView objects you created outside your `updateSilhouetteView` method, whereas he made it so you create a whole new UIImageView reference for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should create a new object for each UIImageView and work as expected. Basically, I am creating a new instance of UIImageView and then adding it to the array. You were adding the same instance, again and again. As a result, the stack view is getting a reference to only 2 distinct UIImageView instances.

```
@IBOutlet weak var silhouetteStack: UIStackView!
//let boy = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boy"))
//let girl = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "girl"))
var silhouettes: [UIImageView] = []
var num = 3

func viewDidLoad() {
    silhouetteStack.distribution = .fillEqually
}

func updateSilhouetteView() {
    for n in 0..<num {
        if n % 2 == 0 {
            silhouettes.append(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "boy")))
            //silhouettes[n].image = UIImage(named: "boy")
            print("boy")
        } else {
            silhouettes.append(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "girl")))
            //silhouettes[n].image = UIImage(named: "girl")
            print("girl")
        }
        silhouettes[n].frame = CGRect(x: 210, y: 500, width: 205, height: 120)
        silhouettes[n].contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        silhouetteStack.addArrangedSubview(silhouettes[n])
    }
}
```

Comment: Parth, Thanks for your response.  I copied your code, but I'm still getting the same results:
num = 1 -> one 'boy' on the screen
num = 2 -> a 'boy' and 'girl' on the screen
num = 3 -> two 'boy' on the screen
num = 4 -> a 'boy' and 'girl' on the screen

Comment: Parth, I got it to work!  Thanks for your help!  The key was adding
```
silhouetteStack.distribution = .fillEqually
```
The images were all there, they were just stacked on top of one another

Comment: Oh good! That's how you tweak the code and learn! I will add that to the answer... Also, can you accept the answer?